# Different Smooth Shading in Edit vs. Object Mode

Tags: reflection

I've modeled this phone and wondered why the shading looks right in edit mode and wrong in object/rendered Mode. (Top ist Object Mode/Bottom is Edit Mode).

I'm using eevee and the Boolean Modifiers won't change anything on applying them.

[image: Object Mode]
[image: Edit Mode]

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange Simon! Edit mode does change a few things, like disabling certain modifiers. A quick way to see if it's a mesh or setting issue is to make a new mesh object (can be anything) then in the Object Data tab of the new mesh go to the top and in the little menu at the top choose your phone mesh data. This will make the new object have the same mesh, but without any modifiers or settings that edit mode might be changing or disabling. If the problem still exists, we know it's not a setting or modifier issue.

Comment: Are you sure you are changing settings based on the appearance in Render mode and not Look-Dev mode? Look-Dev mode has fixed lighting settings that are not realistic in order to save memory while previewing. It ignores all of your lights. Those viewport modes are the square buttons in the top-right of the Blender 2.8 viewport and are (in order) Xray, Wireframe, Solid, Look-Dev, Render

Comment: @Brenticus shouldn't this be an answer rather than comment?

Comment: @hatinacat2000 shouldn't this be an answer rather than comment?

Comment: Not necessarily. What I wrote was more of a guess that could be looked into. After looking at your image closer, it's definitely something to do with a modifier. I'll try and give a proper answer when I have a chance.